# About Divergence in polar coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, coordinate-systems, differentiation

I've got a conductor in a cylinder shape that is rotating with angular velocity $\omega$ around its axis, that correspond to the $z$ axis

I want to calculate the electric field and the density of electric charge.

I have no problem finding $$E = \frac{m_e \omega^2r}{|q_e|} u_r$$ where $m_e$ and $q_e$ are the mass and  electric charge of the electron, and $u_r$ is the versor directed towards the center of the circle (and is thereofore perpendicular to the $z$ axis)

(I know that I had to use several approximation here, which are pretty standard to be honest, but that's not the point as the result appear to be right according to the textbook)

To determin now the density of eletric charge, I would use maxwell's equation

$$\nabla \cdot E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

$E$ is expressed in cylindrical coordinates, though (am I right?)

So the divergence would be

$$\nabla \cdot E = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial rE}{\partial r} = \frac{2m_e \omega^2}{|q_e|} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

On the book there is written though that

> for a vector field that depends solely upon $r$ directed toward the
> centre of the circle, the divergence is just $$\nabla \cdot E =
>  \frac{dE}{dr} = \frac{m_e \omega^2}{|q_e|}$$

I don't understand what he means and why I'm wrong.

Comment: Their formula for divergence is wrong and yours is right. This is easily check by taking the divergence of the electric field create by a line of charge $\sim \frac{1}{r}$.

Comment: you weren't trying to find surface charge density instead of volume charge density by the way were you?

Comment: I was looking for volume charge density. Surface charge density would be equal to the discontituity of the elctric field times $\epsilon_0$, right?

Comment: that is correct.